# How to load .htaccess from Grunt File

Tags: php, .htaccess, gruntjs

My directory looks like so

```
Project 
-- dev
   -- .htaccess
   -- .index.php
-- dist

Gruntfile.js
node_modules
package.json
```

I'm trying to open a persistent PHP server using Grunt, which is working however I want to also the .htaccess the file, but Grunt won't recognise it.

Currently my PHP file looks like so:

```
php: {
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['dev/styles/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:dev']
            },
            scripts: {
                files: 'dev/scripts/javascript/*.js',
                tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify']
            }
        },
        options: {
            keepalive: true,
            open: true,
            base: 'dev',
            port: 8000,
            router: '.htaccess'
        }
    }
```

Once the php server opens the following error occurs:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '.htaccess' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try adding `dot:true` to your options</s>

```
options: { dot: true },
```

On further reading I think that the router file is supposed to be a file that will be run at the startup of the server. If this script returns false, then the requested resource is returned as-is.

So it should be a .php file, try replacing .htaccess with a dummy file and see if the error goes away.

Here is one sample file

```
<?php
// router.php 
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is 
} else {
    echo "<p>Thanks for using grunt :)</p>";
}
?>
```